# Как улучшить код на PHP? (циклы и условия)

Tags: php, инспекция-кода, циклы, рефакторинг

Подскажите как можно улучшить этот код, а то мне кажется что с ним что-то не так.

```
foreach ($newModules['MODULES'] as $newModule) {
        foreach(self::getInstallModules() as $installModule) {
            if ($installModule['TITLE'] == $newModule['TITLE']) {
                if($newModule['INFO']['VERSION'] > $installModule['VERSION']){
                    $results[] = [
                        'NAME' => $newModule['NAME'],
                        'OLD_VERSION' => $installModule['VERSION'],
                        'NEW_VERSION' => $newModule['INFO']['VERSION'],
                        'DESCRIPTION' => $newModule['DESCRIPTION']
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что-то не так скорее всего из-за `$newModule['INFO']['VERSION'] > $installModule['VERSION'])`

Comment: двойной цикл тут костылем кажется для поиска соответствий  в массивах. title бы сделать ключами, пересечь массивы, и потом отфильтровать остатки. но по объему кода меньше не станет. так что смысла нет особого

Answer (score 0):

большую часть вашего кода тут занимает поиск соответствий в двух массивах. Поскольку пхп имеет и встроенные функции для поиска схожений массивов, то можно воспользоваться ими.

Пример исходных данных:

```
$newModules = [
            ['title' => "module-2", 'version' => 1],
            ['title' => "module-3", 'version' => 2],
            ['title' => "module-4", 'version' => 3],
        ];

$oldModules = [
            ['title' => "module-1", 'version' => 1],
            ['title' => "module-2", 'version' => 1],
            ['title' => "module-3", 'version' => 1],
            ['title' => "module-4", 'version' => 1],
            ['title' => "module-5", 'version' => 1],
];
```

и используем `array_uintersect` не совсем по назначению:

```
$result = [];
$data = array_uintersect($newModules, $oldModules, function($n, $o) use (&$result){
                $c = strcmp($n['title'], $o['title']);

                if($c == 0 && $n['version'] > $o['version']){
                    $result[] = [
                        'title' => $o['title'],
                        'old_version' => $o['version'],
                        'new_version' => $n['version'],
                        'description' => null
                    ];                      
                }
                return $c;
            });

print_r($result);
```

но честно сказать, не знаю, лучше ли будет этот код, чем ваш. фактически просто спрятали двойной цикл за функцией.